# Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to insert a new table row into a custom wpdb table. The data is coming from a form posted to a script.

I'm declaring global $wpdb at the start of the script, and inserting into the db, but for some reason it doesn't like the query function, which WordPress recommends to use in the codex.
i got this error Fatal error: Call to a member function query()

this is my code:

```
<?php

global $wpdb;
if($_POST){
$post_id = $_POST['post_id'];

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$city = $_POST['city'];
$tell = $_POST['tell'];

$date_m  = $_POST['date_m'];
$date_y  = $_POST['date_y'];
$consent  = $_POST['consent'];
$check_error = 0;

if (!isset($name) || $name == ''){

echo "empty";
$check_error = 1;
}

elseif (!isset($email) || $email == ''){
echo "empty";
$check_error = 1;
}
$name = mysql_real_escape_string($name);
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($email);
$city = mysql_real_escape_string($city);
$tell = mysql_real_escape_string($tell);
$date_m  = mysql_real_escape_string($date_m);
$date_y  = mysql_real_escape_string($date_y);
$consent  = mysql_real_escape_string($consent);
$query = "INSERT INTO {$wpdb->prefix}kishvote SET ";
$query .= "post_id = '" . $post_id . "', ";
$query .= "date_timevote = '" . date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s' ) . "', ";
$query .= "u_name = '" . $name . "', ";
$query .= "u_city = '" . $city . "', ";
$query .= "u_mail = '" . $email . "', ";
$query .= "u_tell = '" . $tell . "', ";
$query .= "date_m = '" . $date_m . "', ";
$query .= "date_y = '" . $date_y . "', ";
$query .= "consent = '" . $consent . "', ";

$success = $wpdb->query( $query );

        if ($success) {
            $error = 0;
            echo "submit";
        } else {
            $error = 1;
            echo 'eror dade';
        }
 }
?>
```

Comment: apparently $wpdb is not an object...
it is impossible to say why based on what you've posted here. try `var_dump()` for example to see what it contains.
besides that, using globals is a very bad practice and you should try to avoid using it.

Comment: Where have you placed this code , functions.php . ?

Comment: try to put `global $wpdb` after `if($_post){`